# Why problems with importing Matplotlib module in Python occur?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was following the guide on the official matplotlib site and I typed this into my cmd;

```
python -m pip install -U pip

python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

Although matplotlib seems to be installed, when trying to import it in Python file I receive ModuleNotFoundError.
As a newcomer to Python, I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: How are you executing the Python file? Open the Python interpreter in the cmd (write `python` and press enter) and then try importing matplotlib with `import matplotlib`. If no error happens, it means that the Python installation in your cmd is not the same as the installation you tried to execute the file with.

Comment: I was executing the Python file using Sublime Text. Actually after following your instructions no error ocurred, nevertheless I don't fully understand why Python installation in my cmd may differ from the Sublime Text's installation.